# Fullcalendar v5 how to show and hide events with menu nav nav-tabs

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I would like to show and hide events with a menu like bootstrap nav nav-tabs.

When on tab I click Event1 show only event with "cid: "1"", Event2 show only event with "cid: "2"" and ALL show all events.

Can anyone help me develop this?
Based on this question [Fullcalendar v5 how to show and hide events with checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198394/fullcalendar-v5-how-to-show-and-hide-events-with-checkbox) I made a codepen based on checkbox only for starting...
https://codepen.io/berettatim/pen/rNeXwLm

html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li onclick="javascript:CalendarTypeSet(1)" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#CalTab1" style="font-size:16px;"><b>EVENT1</b></a></li>
    <li onclick="javascript:CalendarTypeSet(2)" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#CalTab2" style="font-size:16px;"><b>EVENT2</b></a></li>
    <li onclick="javascript:CalendarTypeSet(3)" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#CalTab3" style="font-size:16px;"><b>EVENT3</b></a></li>
    <li onclick="javascript:CalendarTypeSet('all')" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#CalTabAll" style="font-size:16px;"><b>ALL</b></a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input class="cs" value="1" type="checkbox" checked>Calendar1<br>
    <input class="cs" value="2" type="checkbox" checked>Calendar2
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </div>
```

script:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    now: "2020-07-11",
    scrollTime: "00:00",
    aspectRatio: 1.8,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "today prev,next",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth"
    },
    initialView: "dayGridMonth",
    events: function (fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
      successCallback([
        {
          id: "1",
          title: "event1",
          start: "2020-07-01 19:30",
          end: "2020-07-02 19:30",
          backgroundColor: "#39CCCC",
          cid: "1"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          title: "event2",
          start: "2020-07-09 19:30",
          end: "2020-07-10 19:30",
          backgroundColor: "#F012BE",
          cid: "2"
        }
      ]);
    },
    eventDidMount: function (arg) {
      var cs = document.querySelectorAll(".cs");
      cs.forEach(function (v) {
        if (v.checked) {
          if (arg.event.extendedProps.cid === v.value) {
            arg.el.style.display = "block";
          }
        } else {
          if (arg.event.extendedProps.cid === v.value) {
            arg.el.style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
  calendar.render();

  var csx = document.querySelectorAll(".cs");
  csx.forEach(function (el) {
    el.addEventListener("change", function () {
      calendar.refetchEvents();
      console.log(el);
    });
  });
});

//Not sure for this...
    function CalendarTypeSet(fTip)
    {
         var x = document.getElementById('cal_tip');
         x.value=fTip;
         //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
    calendar.rerenderEvents('#calendar');
    }
```

Comment: What's your specific question or problem then? Where are you stuck with your requirement, exactly?

Comment: I take this part of code from a fullcalendar3 but I don't know how to upgrade to v5, so I thought that is simpler to start from the past question about checks, but I don't how to integrate in the right way, in the website of fullcalendar I didn't find an example that explain this kind of utilization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes you need are more related to the use of tabs than to the difference between fullCalendar 3 and 5. Compared to checkboxes, only one option can be selected at once, so you need to find out from the tabs themselves which tab is currently open.

So here's a simple idea which can work: when a tab is shown, run a function. In that function, call the calendar's `refetchEvents()` method (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents). Then you can use the calendar's `eventDataTransform` callback to decide whether that event should be displayed on the calendar or not, based on which tab is currently "active". See (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform) - this is preferable to `eventDidMount` because it runs before the event is rendered onto the calendar, rather than afterwards.

Something like this should do it:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li data-tabid="1" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#CalTab1" style="font-size:16px;"><b>EVENT1</b></a></li>
      <li data-tabid="2" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#CalTab2" style="font-size:16px;"><b>EVENT2</b></a></li>
      <li data-tabid="3" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#CalTab3" style="font-size:16px;"><b>EVENT3</b></a></li>
      <li data-tabid="all" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#CalTabAll" style="font-size:16px;"><b>ALL</b></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="calendar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialDate: "2020-07-01",
    aspectRatio: 1.8,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "today prev,next",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth"
    },
    initialView: "dayGridMonth",
    events: function (fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
      successCallback([
        {
          id: "1",
          title: "event1",
          start: "2020-07-01 19:30",
          end: "2020-07-02 19:30",
          backgroundColor: "#39CCCC",
          cid: "1"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          title: "event2",
          start: "2020-07-09 19:30",
          end: "2020-07-10 19:30",
          backgroundColor: "#F012BE",
          cid: "2"
        }
      ]);
    },
    eventDataTransform: function (eventData) {
      var selectedTab = document.querySelector(".nav-tabs li a.active").dataset.tabid;
          if (selectedTab == "all" || eventData.cid == selectedTab) {
            return eventData;
          }
          else return false; //discard the event
    }
  });
  calendar.render();

  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      calendar.refetchEvents();
  });
});
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/abZZEbM

Comment: Actually I thought of a better way than my original version, without using globals - see edited version