# How to filter events based on multiple checkbox values on FullCalendar V5?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, filter, fullcalendar

I trying to learn Fullcalendar v5 and have now come to adding filters. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198394/fullcalendar-v5-how-to-show-and-hide-events-with-checkbox) I found a Codepen example with checkbox filtering. Now how do I add checkbox filter for a different extendedProps.

So now i have this HTML for checkboxes

```
<input class="cs" value="Movie" type="checkbox" checked>Movie
<input class="cs" value="Series" type="checkbox" checked>Series

<input class="cs" value="Netflix" type="checkbox" checked>Netflix
<input class="cs" value="Disney" type="checkbox" checked>Disney
```

The eventdata is

```
{
          id: "1",
          title: "event1",
          start: "2020-07-01 19:30",
          end: "2020-07-02 19:30",
          backgroundColor: "#39CCCC",
          cid: "Movie",
          sid: "Netflix"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          title: "event2",
          start: "2020-07-09 19:30",
          end: "2020-07-10 19:30",
          backgroundColor: "#F012BE",
          cid: "Series",
          sid: "Disney"
        }
```

And now I need change this below to include arg.event.extendedProps.sid

```
eventDidMount: function (arg) {
      var cs = document.querySelectorAll(".cs");
      cs.forEach(function (v) {
        if (v.checked) {
          if (arg.event.extendedProps.cid === v.value) {
            arg.el.style.display = "block";
          }
        } else {
          if (arg.event.extendedProps.cid === v.value) {
            arg.el.style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
  calendar.render();

  var csx = document.querySelectorAll(".cs");
  csx.forEach(function (el) {
    el.addEventListener("change", function () {
      calendar.refetchEvents();
      console.log(el);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What's the meaning o intention of **let selector = document.querySelector("#selector1,#selector2");**? If you have two conditions, use 2 condition values and use them in the **if**. It's not about assigning 2 values to a variable.

Comment: So maybe `if (arg.event.extendedProps.cid === v.value || arg.event.extendedProps.sid === v.value) { ` ?? And/or do you need to add some more checkboxes as well? It's a bit unclear where you're stuck, or what you've tried so far.

Comment: Sorry if it is unclear. I have made this Codepen [link](https://codepen.io/Bo-Kj-rgaard/pen/bGKVOyE)

I've added your code and it now works but I do have a checkbox section more (Genres). And that can include more than one value seperated by comma so exact match will not work. So I am stuck at adding the check for genres checkboxes and how to do partial matching if possible.

Comment: `that can include more than one value seperated by comma`...don't do that. Supply it as an array into the extended property, then you can use [array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to test for a match trivially.